# How to set state based on document.body but before render (react)

Tags: reactjs

I have a toggle whose defaultChecked I want to set based on the document.body.getAttribute("data-theme").

If the theme is light set the `defaultChecked = ""` and if not `defaultChecked = "true"`

I have realized that the problem is that the site is not fully loaded when I want to do something like this:

```
this.state = {
  checked: document.body.getAttribute("data-theme") === "light" ? "" : "true",
};
```

which means that I always get something truthy.

here is the complete component:

```
class Theme extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: document.body.getAttribute("data-theme") === "light" ? "" : "true",
    };
    this.handelChange = this.handelChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let theme = localStorage.getItem("data-theme");
    document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
  }

  handelChange(evt) {
    if (evt.target.checked) {
      document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
      localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "dark");
    } else {
      document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
      localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "light");
    }

    let lineColor = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue("--sidebar-color");
    if (typeof InstallTrigger === "undefined") {
      lineColor = lineColor.substring(1);
    }
    this.props.colorChange(lineColor);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onChange={this.handelChange} className="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <label className="theme-switch" htmlFor="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.checked} />
          <div className="slider round"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Theme;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
class Theme extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: localStorage.getItem("data-theme") === "light" ? "" : "true"
    };
    this.handelChange = this.handelChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let theme = localStorage.getItem("data-theme");
    this.setState({
      checked: theme === "light" ? "" : "true"
    });
  }

  handelChange(evt) {
    if (evt.target.checked) {
      localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "dark");
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "light");
    }

    let lineColor = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue(
      "--sidebar-color"
    );
    if (typeof InstallTrigger === "undefined") {
      lineColor = lineColor.substring(1);
    }
    this.props.colorChange(lineColor);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onChange={this.handelChange} className="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <label className="theme-switch" htmlFor="checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="checkbox"
            defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
          />
          <div className="slider round"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG you are absolutely right, I was thinking that I had two situations, one with a new visitor and one with a visitor that has come before. But it doesn't actually matter. Thank you

Comment: @Saoma Have fun coding ;)